# \frac{}{} tex command is not rendered properly .Please help

Tags: bug, mathjax

Recently I have faced a problem in which the `\frac{}{}` tex command is not rendered properly by my chrome browser. The line between the denominator and numerator gets longer than desired. In Mozilla there is no such problem. Is there is something wrong with my browser?

I have attached the image below. The image is of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/169412/264).

[image]
Also the problem is not only with this particular post, it is with all the text that uses
 `\frac{}{}`.My google chrome version is $(21.0.1180.41)$ and I am using windows $7 ,64$bit system.
I would like to mention one more thing as I right-click on the math expression > Math Settings > Math Renderer > SVG.Then this problem doesn't arises.And if instead of SVG ,HTML-CSS is choosen than the problem persists.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 20.0.1132.57 on Windows 7 64-bit, and it looks fine to me. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @ZevChonoles My google chrome version is "google chrome (21.0.1180.41)".And I also using Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: I will look into it next week (am on the road so can't do it before then).  Does reloading the page help?

Comment: @DavideCervone Thanks for your time sir.Well reloading doesn't help.Also before this problem occurred I had installed LyX.Can it remotely be the cause of the problem? I don't know much about Latex and mathjax etc so I may be talking nonsense here.

Comment: The thread you link to looks fine for me, but I see [something similar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/INIOL.png) in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/170348/5363) (Mac OS X 10.6.8, on both, Safari 5.1.7 (6534.57.2) and on Firefox 13.0.1), but I can't tell if this is related.

Comment: Did this do the same naughty thing with ${\over }$?

Comment: @ncmathsadist I didn't understand you question !!

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem, but I only have version 20.0.1132.57 which my Chrome says is up to date.  Are you using a beta version?  Chrome is buggy enough in its release versions, so I wouldn't be surprised if this were a new bug.  In any case, we're not prepared to make changes to MathJax for beta versions of browsers that may not be present when the version is released.

Comment: @t.b., what you are seeing is a different issue (having to do with automatic line-breaking within the numerator of the fraction).  I'll look into that, too, but it is a separate problem.

Comment: @ncmathsadist, yes, `{...\over...}` works internally in MathJax the same as `\frac{}{}`, so both should produce the same results.

Comment: @SaurabhHota, does this happen for you with *all* fractions, or just the ones on the page you cite?

Comment: @SaurabhHota, did you zoom in on the page when you had this problem?  I have another report similar to yours, but it is dependent on zooming in or out.

Comment: @DavideCervone No I didn't tried zoom in back then but now my problem is solved as I have changed my google chrome version.

Comment: OK, thanks for the extra info.

Comment: @DavideCervone yes you were right the problem arises when I zoom in .(google chrome version 21.0.1180.60 -- which is not a beta version)

Comment: Right, they released v21 a day or two ago.  I will have to look into it more closely now.  Thanks for the extra details.  It looks like they have messed up the relative dimensions during zooming.

Comment: I have opened an [issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/276) on the MathJax GitHub site for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathJax v2.1 should resolve this issue for Chrome users.  Since math.SE is using a beta copy of MathJax v2.1, you should see the correct rendering at this point (you may need to clear the cache and reload the page, or even restart Chrome in order to get the new version -- check the MathJax About box from the MathJax contextual menu to verify that all the files listed show v2.1).

Please let me know if you continue to see problems with the fraction bars.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue as well.

I have added a screenshot of the issue from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178823/prove-the-trig-equation). I am on Chrome Version 21.0.1180.57, Max OS X 10.7.4.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem; it turned out to be a zooming issue. Pressing ctrl-zero fixed it.