# what links here?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, linked-questions

Do we have a "what links here" feature such as that on Wikipedia?  One would click on "what links here" and see a list of questions, answers, comments, etc., that link to the question or answer or whatever, that one is looking at?

Comment: Is this feature request from meta.SO approximately what you want: [Let linked questions have an arrow indicating which question is linking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66651/)? Or do you want something more advanced - e.g. display individually the list of comments/answers/questions which link to a given answer/question/comment? (I am not sure that doing this in a such detail would be feasible.)

Answer (score 12):

Yes. It appears on the right, between the **Community Bulletin** and the **Related**, if there are links to show, under the title **Linked**.

Let me add a link to a previously unlinked post (on meta), [\frac{}{} tex command is not rendered properly .Please help](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/frac-tex-command-is-not-rendered-properly-please-help) which will now show both on this page's Linked and this post will appear on the linked post's Linked.

---

To explicitly state it: the above feature works for **all** SE sites, including this meta and including the main site. This is a software feature, not a site-specific feature.

The links are added when links appear in the question, in the answers, or in the comments. As discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66651/let-linked-questions-have-an-arrow-indicating-which-question-is-linking) all these links appear together and there is no "clean" way to see what is linked to, and what is linked from, the current page.

These links are only site-internal, so if I link to meta.SO the link will not show; if I link to meta from the main (or vice versa) the link will not show either.

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize that the "Linked" section had that functionality. *This answer is helpful.*

Comment: But I meant on the main site, not on meta.  It hadn't occurred to me that anyone might think I meant meta.

Comment: Is this something that appears only if something actually does link to the posting?

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's on the main site as well. e.g. [my post here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116138/solve-x-frac1x-0?lq=1).

Comment: @Michael, all SE sites, main or meta, have this feature. "Is this something that appears only if something actually does link to the posting?" - yes, there should be a link either in the question, answers or comments for it to appear.

Comment: This all shows the advantage of Wikipedia's way of doing it: You're reading the article about omphalology, and you click on "what links here", and you see a list of all pages that link to that page, and if there are none, you see a message that says there are none.  If the "what links here" button appeared ONLY when there is at least one page that links to the page you're looking at, then you might not find out that that feature exists.

Comment: @Michael: The same feature is shared by all SE sites. And Yes, if there is nothing, then it won't appear.

Comment: @cardinal: I think he misread my answer...

Comment: @Michael: I have a hard time producing screenshots with my current system, so instead I described *what and where and when* this thing appears, in hope that you can understand that I meant it both here and on the main site.

Comment: Perhaps it is useful to add, that the list on the right is combination of *What links here* and *Where this page links*, see meta.SO [Let linked questions have an arrow indicating which question is linking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66651/let-linked-questions-have-an-arrow-indicating-which-question-is-linking). It might also be useful to know that it is created from links in questions, answers and comments, including answers and comments that were deleted IIRC; meta.SO [Posts linked in deleted answers still show up under “Linked”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64743/).

Comment: Addition to my above comment - as you can see in the link I've given there: *The linked / related questions are rebuilt every 30 days, so at that time any deleted links will be culled.* So the thing I wrote about deleted answers and comments is not true.