# Can one get referrers of the trafic that caused upvotes on my answer?

Tags: support, linked-questions

An [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133628/distribution-of-hitting-time-of-line-by-brownian-motion/133971#133971) of mine from mid-April got up-voted twice within 24 hours today. I would like to find out if this was caused by somebody linking to it in comments/questions/answers.

I am hoping there is an established way to do this, and would be grateful if somebody pointed me to it.

Comment: When you have a look at the linked questions, there is [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180488/probability-for-brownian-motion) with a [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180488/probability-for-brownian-motion?lq=1#comment415876_180488) linking to your answer. It was asked today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever a link to some answer/question is given in any post, the two questions (the one with the link and the one to which the link goes) are linked to each other. Linked questions are shown on the right, above related questions. More details can be found, for example, in this thread: [what links here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4662/what-links-here)